# Filtering HTTP 1.0 with AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I was thinking of filtering the HTTP 1.0 request at the AWS WAF level, and found some documentation on setting WAF rules. But not finding an option for setting the filtering rules.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, checking the HTTP version is not supported in WAF rules - at this time.